# Exchange 2010 SP2 Message Records Management Logging

Tags: exchange-2010

Is it possible to log the Managed Folder Assistant's activity in regards to retention policies in Exchange 2010 SP2?  I would like to take a closer look at a mailbox that is being skipped over when I issue the `Start-ManagedFolderAssistant jdoe` cmdlet.  I have many other mailboxes where this works fine and they're configured identically.